# Remove the Kronecker operator in $\mathrm{trace((\Sigma^{-1}\otimes S^{-1})A})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, trace, kronecker-product

I am not sure if I can remove the Kronecker operator in the following formula
$$\mathrm{trace((\Sigma^{-1}\otimes S^{-1})A}),$$
where $\Sigma,S$ are positive-semidefinite and symmetric, and $A$ is symmetric. Any help would be appreciated.

### Update:

---

@greg claimed in the answer below that we can "**exactly represent $A$ as a finite sum of Kronecker products**." I am wondering how to obtain this exact representation. To be more specific, I have $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & R
\end{array}\right),
 $$ where $R$ is a symmetric and positive semi-definite matrix, and its dimension is $k \times k$, $k=1,\dots,\mathrm{ncol}(A)$. The ultimate goal is to calculate the derivative $$\frac{\partial \mathrm{trace((\Sigma^{-1}\otimes S^{-1})A})}{\partial \Sigma}.$$
This is related to question:
[Derivative involving the trace of a Kronecker product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004869/derivative-involving-the-trace-of-a-kronecker-product/2006123).
I did read [Van Loan and Pitsianis (1993)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/61ae/81bbbf527e3463abe8d1c067d935de129fe5.pdf), but did not find a solution.

Comment: I'm just beginning to read about Tensor analysis on Manifolds. Do you have any tips?

Comment: @bd1251252, sorry I only know Kronecker operator.

Comment: Found the solution in Section 6 [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377042700003939/1-s2.0-S0377042700003939-main.pdf?_tid=62d338a0-d51f-11e6-87c3-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1483824326_c10f15eb9b78c5f9f7445f906ca98345).

Comment: Hi, I am currently having the same problem, but the link to Section 6 is not valid anymore. Could you give me a reference to the solution you found? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the function in terms of the Frobenius product as
$$
  f = A^T:(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes S^{-1})
$$
If you had a Kronecker Product factorization for $A=B\otimes C$, where $B,C$ are the same dimensions as $\Sigma,S$ respectively.  Then you could re-write the function to eliminate the Kronecker product as follows
$$ \eqalign {
 f &= (B^T\otimes C^T):(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes S^{-1}) \cr
   &= (B^T:\Sigma^{-1})\,(C^T:S^{-1}) \cr 
   &= {\rm tr}(B\Sigma^{-1})\,\,{\rm tr}(CS^{-1}) \cr 
}$$
If you don't have an exact Kronecker factorization, a search for "Kronecker Product approximation" will turn up lots of software.

Further, you can exactly represent $A$ as a finite sum of Kronecker products
$$\eqalign{
  A &= \sum^r_{k=1} B_k\otimes C_k \cr
  f &= \sum^r_{k=1} {\rm tr}(B_k\Sigma^{-1})\,\,{\rm tr}(C_kS^{-1}) \cr
}$$
But I'm not sure it's worth all of this effort simply to avoid a single Kronecker product.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this thorough answer! I found the question can be greatly simplified by letting $D$ be a scalar and $Z$ be a vector.