# Derivative of the trace of a Kronecker product

Tags: derivatives, trace, kronecker-product

I am trying to compute the derivative

$\frac{\partial}{\partial W} \text{Tr}(W^\top A (I\otimes W)B),$

where $W\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times d}, I\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times T}$ is an identity matrix, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times DT}$, and  $B\in\mathbb{R}^{dT\times d}$.

I have found a similar post:
[Derivative involving the trace of a Kronecker product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004869/derivative-involving-the-trace-of-a-kronecker-product)

but it seems that the method is not applicable to my problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The technique from the linked post can be applied to the current problem.

Write the function in terms of the trace/Frobenius product, and find its differential 
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= W:A(I\otimes W)B = A^TWB^T:(I\otimes W) \cr
d\phi &= A(I\otimes W)B:dW + A^TWB^T:(I\otimes dW)
}$$
At this point, we need use the Pitsianis decomposition on that last term.
$$\eqalign{
A^TWB^T &= \sum_k Y_k\otimes Z_k \cr
}$$ 
The matrices $(Y_k,Z_k)$ are shaped like $(I,W)$ respectively.

Finish calculating the differential, then on to the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= A(I\otimes W)B:dW + \sum_kY_k\otimes Z_k:(I\otimes dW) \cr
 &= \Big(A(I\otimes W)B + \sum_k(I:Y_k)Z_k\Big):dW \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= A(I\otimes W)B + \sum_k {\rm tr}(Y_k)\,Z_k \cr\cr
}$$

---

Another technique uses the SVD of 
$$B=\sum_k\sigma_ku_kv_k^T$$
to handle the second term of $d\phi$ as follows.
$$\eqalign{
A^TW:(I\otimes dW)B
 &= \sum_k\,A^TW:(I\otimes dW)\sigma_ku_kv_k^T \cr
 &= \sum_k\,(A^TW\sigma_kv_k):(I\otimes dW)u_k \cr
 &= \sum_k\,q_k:{\rm vec}(dW\,U_k) \cr
 &= \sum_k\,Q_k:dW\,U_k \cr
 &= \sum_k\,Q_kU_k^T:dW \cr
}$$
where
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(Q_k) &= q_k = A^TW\sigma_kv_k \cr
{\rm vec}(U_k) &= u_k \cr
}$$
Yielding the gradient as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= A(I\otimes W)B + \sum_k Q_kU_k^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! But one question is: $A^\top W B^\top$ is also a function of $W$, so we cannot do the decomposition, am I right?

Comment: The dependence of the function on the $A^TWB^T$ term was accounted for by the first term in the differential expression. Perform the Pitsianis decomposition using the current value of $W$.