# A matrix differentiation with trace and kronecker product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm new to matrix calculus and want to differentiate the following function w.r.t $X$, $Y$
$$\phi(X,Y) = Y^TA^T(L\otimes X):Y^TA^T(L\otimes X)
=tr((L\otimes X)^TAYY^TA^T(L\otimes X)) $$
I know the derivative w.r.t $Y$, but have no idea how to start it w.r.t $X$
I have checked some related questions and solutions, but I still have no idea how the 'differential' $d\phi$ are derived.
Is there any reference about calculating the differential of a matrix?
Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: The process I recommend is this: express $\phi(X + H, Y)$ in the form
$$
\phi(X + H,Y) = \phi(X,Y) + M:H + R
$$
where the remainder $R$ satisfies $R = O(H^2)$, i.e. every term in $R$ contains at least two $H$'s in the product. Once you have done this, the differential can be expressed as
$$
d\phi = M:dX.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to ask a question first: What is the definition of the differential? In [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644106/derivative-of-the-trace-of-a-kronecker-product?rq=1) I don't know how greg get $d \phi$ from $\phi$ easily, is there a systematic way to find out the differential? Sorry it's my first time to deal with matrix calculus, and I can't find other websites teaching how to get  the differential of a matrix.

Comment: It's definitely tricky to find good resources; I've mostly pieced things together on my own. In any case, it looks like greg used a "product rule"

Comment: Also, the specific procedure I recommended is geared towards getting a [matrix layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Numerator-layout_notation) for the derivative. In general, one only needs to write
$$
\phi(X + dX,Y) - \phi(X,Y) = f(dX) + R
$$
with $f$ a linear function of $dX$ and $R = O(\|dX\|^2)$. From there, $f(dX)$ is the differential $d\phi(X,Y).$

Comment: Yes it look like a result of product rule, but I don't know how the properties(like product rule, chain rule) of single-variable differentiation are extended to matrix case. So you don't have any recommendation of textbooks or paper about matrix differentiation properties?

Comment: I will try the method you mentioned above later, thanks for your guides. You just saved my life :-D

Comment: See also greg's recommendation in the comment on his answer

Answer (score 2):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
Define $B=(L\otimes X)^TAY$ and assume the following sizes for the matrices
$$\eqalign{
 m,n &= {\rm size}(X) \\
 p,q &= {\rm size}(L) \\
 mp,r &= {\rm size}(A) \\
 r,s &= {\rm size}(Y) \\
 nq,s &= {\rm size}(B) \\
}$$
Kronecker products can be vectorized with the aid of a
[Commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $\,(K_{np})$
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(L\otimes X)
 &= \left(I_q\otimes K_{np}\otimes I_m\right)\cdot
\left({\rm vec}(L)\otimes I_m\otimes I_n\right)\cdot {\rm vec}(X) \\
 &\doteq  M\,{\rm vec}(X) \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of $B$.
Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= B^T:B^T \\
d\phi
 &= 2B^T:dB^T \\
 &= 2B^T:(AY)^T(L\otimes dX) \\
 &= 2AYB^T:(L\otimes dX) \\
 &= 2\,{\rm vec}(AYB^T):M\;{\rm vec}(dX) \\
 &= 2\,M^T{\rm vec}(AYB^T):{\rm vec}(dX) \\
 &= 2\;{\rm devec}\Big(M^T{\rm vec}(AYB^T)\Big):dX \\
\p{\phi}{X} &= 2\;{\rm devec}\Big(M^T{\rm vec}(AYB^T)\Big) \\
}$$
The hardest part of the process is freeing $dX$ from the Kronecker term.

Vectorization/devectorization was used to handle the Kronecker product
in this example, but one might also employ the Singular value decomposition
or the Pitsianis decomposition of the matrix $(AYB^T)$,
both of which were demonstrated in your
[linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644106) answer.

Another possibility is a
[block Kronecker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735523)
decomposition of the $(AYB^T)$ matrix.

The key idea is that the Kronecker and Frobenius products have a nice distributive property
$$(A\otimes B):(C\otimes dX) \;=\; (A:C)\,B:dX$$
for compatibly dimensioned matrices.

Comment: Following the discussion in the comments on the question, do you have any references on matrix calculus that would be helpful to a beginner?

Comment: Magnus and Neudecker's "_Matrix Differential Calculus_" covers differentials in the latter part of the book. I also like Hjorungnes's "_Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_"

Comment: I got it, thanks you guys' help. These answer are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The differential in this case will be
$$
d\phi = 2 Y^TA^T(L \otimes X):Y^TA^T(L \otimes dX).
$$